# Sluggish vertical scrolling performance in Angular NGX Datatable

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, ngx-datatable

currently we are expecting poor perfomance in our angular application while scrolling. Even though we are only talking of about 250 entries, the vertical scrolling behaviour is slow and sluggish and happening with a great delay. After some look in the DOM, i saw that on every scroll we update the whole array of row wrappers. Especially the value for ng-reflect-offset-x seems to be changing with every scroll, as shown in the screenshot below. My first thought was, that this rerendering might be the root of our performance issues.

[image: Rerender of whole table]

On top of that we have a horizontal scrollbar, with no purpose. It shows a scrolling potential, which isnt there. We can drag the scrollbar (and the ng-reflect-offset-x values change), but nothing happens on the view of the table. So basically we can pull the thumb of the scrollbar indefinitely, with the offset values reaching values over 4000.

[image]

Here is also a screenshot of the performance graph:

[image]

As you see, there are obviously some problems with the rendering of the table. This only happens in Chrome, in Firefox is everything fine. This is the case at least until I start the debugger for firefox.

Does someone have a clue what is wrong in our setup? Please tell me if you need specific code snippets, as i don't know which you might exactly need.

Comment: did you got the solution for this ?